# php - FPDF - Margin of the first line of each page break - offset

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to create a PDF file using FPDF library and php. Almost everything works fine but the first line of each page (immediately after a page break) exceeds the right margin (and so the end of the page) and part of the text it is not shown.

```
    $pdf = new PDF('P','mm','Letter');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();

    $pdf->lMargin = 15;
    $pdf->rMargin = 15;
    $pdf->tMargin = 20;
    $pdf->bMargin = 10;


    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 30);

    $pdf->newFlowingBlock( 185, 8, 0, 'J' );
    $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 12 );
    $pdf->WriteFlowingBlock( utf8_decode('El Contratista se compromete con '.$cte['nombre_cte'].' a realizar un '.$objeto_contrato_completo.', 
    conforme al alcance y actividades definidas en la Propuesta Técnica y Económica del '.$dia_propuesta.' de ' .$mes_propuesta. ' de '.$ano_propuesta.' 
    presentada por el Contratista, el cual hace parte del presente contrato para todos los efectos legales.'));
    $pdf->finishFlowingBlock();
```

Thanks in advance for your help. (Excuse me, I speak broken English)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6aO9.jpg)

Comment: Your English is fine and understandable, don't worry about it. Why aren't you using the default method [`write`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/write.htm)?

Comment: I'm not very sure, but if my memory serves me right, i read it on another forum because i was having troubles with the justification of the paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Place `$pdf->Ln();` right after when page breaks. It may help.
Page break can be checked by `$pdf->GetY() + 30 > page_height`.